# What are the advantages of showsPrec over show?

Tags: haskell

A job candidate submitted a code sample to me which implements `Show` by using [`showsPrec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec) instead of `show`. This seems like an unusual enough choice that he must've had a reason to do this, but I can't find anything online about the advantages of this.

Is there any reason to use `showsPrec`?

Comment: `showsPrec` is used to implement `show`. It prevents things like `Just (a :- b)` being printed as `Just a :- b`, or `Just [1,2,3]` being printed as `Just ([1,2,3])`.

Comment: Normally, `Show` should always define `showsPrec` rather than `show`.

Comment: @augustss cool, why?

Comment: @Xodarap in [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#shows), you can see that `show` is ultimately defined in terms of `showsPrec`.

Comment: @Xodarap, so you get parenthesis in the right places.

Comment: Like augustss said, this is not "unusual", this is "the correct way to do it". :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `showsPrec` function receives an additional argument: "the operator precedence of the enclosing context".

The main use case of defining `showsPrec` instead of `show` is so that you can decide whether to show your value with parens around it or not. When defining `showsPrec`, it is common to use [`showParen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showParen).

See, for example, [the source for `instance Show KindRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-568)

Comment: Don't forget the efficiency advantage of using `ShowS` over `String` for appending.